# Why is the L silent in "walk" but not in "bulk"?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, linguistics, silent-letters

### TL;DR

Why is the letter L silent in *walk, talk, calm, folk, half, chalk* etc but not silent in *bulk, hulk, milk, silk, bold, bald*?

### Explanation of the question and Research:

The letter L seems to be silent in many words like *walk, talk, calm, folk, half, chalk*. I checked their pronunciations in a few dictionaries and I have never heard anyone pronouncing it in these words. Maybe some people pronounce the L as suggested in [this post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/7w95pk/pronouncing_the_ls_in_talk_walk_etc/) but the standard pronunciation has silent L.

Another post on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-words-have-a-silent-%E2%80%9Cl%E2%80%9D-in-their-spelling-like-Talk-Walk-Balm) suggests two points in which one is "l-vocalization":

> The first one has got something to do with l-vocalisation. In many languages this consonant changes its characteristic over time. Initially, plain ’l’ gets velarized (or dark, in other words), after which the consonant gradually becomes a semi-vowel.
> This is what happened to ‘l’ in a number of English words of Germanic origin such as ‘walk’. Being pronounced /walk/ a long time ago, they changed the pronunciation to /wawk/, and later on to /wɔ:k/ (monophthongisation of ‘au’ is also rather widespread).   [answer by Igor Vegin].

One question ([Where did the L in talk go?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209410/where-did-the-l-in-talk-go/453638#453638)) on this site is similar but it does not explain why the L is pronounced in some words and silent in some words. In this question, the answer by Decapitated Soul says also "L-vocalization" as suggested in Quora's answer but does not explain my question.

Another answer I found is on [Linguist List](https://linguistlist.org/ask-ling/message-details1.cfm?asklingid=200317032) but does not answer my question, instead it says the the L was pronounced at some time but it is silent now.

### My own observations:

The L is silent when it comes between a vowel and consonant. In words where the L is between vowels, the L is not silent like in *filling, killing, color, pillar* etc.

The L **after** /ɔː/ and /ɑː/ and before a consonant is silent in many words like *calm, walk, talk, half, calm* etc.

The L **after** /ɪ/ and before a consonant is not silent like *milk, silk, film* etc.

The L **after** /ʌ/ and before a consonant is not like *hulk, bulk* etc.

### Question:

Is there any rule or this is just random discrepancy? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: I hear/pronounce the "L" in most of those words ("half" being the major exception).

Comment: I don't think I pronounce the L in *any* of these words. Maybe just a slurred W or a (non-rhotic) R

Comment: In British English, (and, I believe, for some but not all US speakers) the 'l' is not pronounced before labial continuants, as _calm_, _palm_, _psalm_, _half_, _calf_, _halve_, _calve_. There are exceptions: I pronounce the 'l' in _salve_, though dictionaries tell me that both pronunciations are used. There is a village near me called "Galphay", and I pronounced it /gælfeɪ/ when I first moved to the area, but the local pronunciation is /gɑːfi/, like "half" and "calf". There is also the name "Ralph", which used to be pronounced "Rafe" in Britain, though that is outdated now.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - It's easier to pronounce the "L" than it is to say "enunciate a postvocalic lateral between a low back rounded vowel and a velar stop".

Comment: @ColinFine Not entirely outdated, though rare .For instance [Ralph Fiennes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Fiennes) pronounces his name as "Rafe"and it is commonly mis-spelt that way.

Comment: For *walk* specificly, note the sense "go" seems from a quick overview to be restricted to English, besides a distant Indic comparand and Nl. *zwalken*, West Fris. *swalkje* "wander" which are attested later than Old English *gewealcan* and rather similar to Old Norse *sveggja* (cp. *swagger, to sway*, not Ger. *schwelgen*?) so that comparison is in order to \*weg'h-, cp. Ger. *bewegen* "move", *wagen* "make a move, dare", also *Waage* "scales" and En. *weight*, but also *way* and *wagon*. Further, if the liquid in \*wankona is n-infix, it is from \*weg'h-, too; maybe *beugen ~ bow* "twist".

Comment: Similarly, *talk* as a supposed diminutive from *tell* ("equivalent to *tell* + *-k*", cp. Ger. *-chen*, e.g. *Mädchen* "girl", *Magd, Maid*) has to be compared to *zeigen* "show, point", Lat. *dico* "say, speak", on the one hand, no doubt, and maybe *cunnan* "speak, know" too. Insofar *frequentative* is mentioned, note that tbese are still a little controversial (when they involve gemminates at least). *Half* is of uncertain origin beyond Proto-Germanic anyhow (cp. perhaps *twelve*, though I find the equation with *two* + *left* not very convincing to be honest)

Comment: "Calma may derive from Late Latin cauma (“heat of the midday sun”),..." Do I need say more!? "Compare also Proto-Germanic \*kalmaz (“frozenness, cold”)." (en. wiktionary). So cool. This should account for both the two mentions of *calm* that you wrote down ;P In sum, I'm suggesting that the lax vowels we might observe as a rule cud be in isolated instances *the consequence* of a sound change, not its cause. These might be involved in further changes though (a chain shift).

Comment: PS: *Chalk* is originally a wanderword. If related to χάλιξ and certain metal words (*xalx* IIRC) the ultimate origin is unknown. The search goes as far as China. This is an especially juicy topic, because early PIE simply had no metal. Sanskrit *karman* "smith" traces a different root, \*kwer- "to make", but if this (and \*kwel- "turn", cf. *wheel*) belonged here, too, then cp. *ceramics*, Latin *creta* "chalk, clay", *calix* "chalice", even Arabic خَلَقَ "create, make", maybe MLG *kule* "pit" (\*kulo "hole; bump", cp. *mine* "Late Latin mina [...] from Proto-Celtic *mēnis (“ore, metal”)"...

Comment: ... "Cognate with Proto-Germanic \*smiþaz (“smith”)), and, if all this wasn't wild enough: Yiddish *Cochem* "(secret) knowledge" (whence Ger. *Puste-Kuchen*, literally "blow..." or "air cake", a nonce word), with "knowledge" somehow fitting to early al-chemy (refer to the Holy Grail legend, which is sometimes described as a chalice instead); thus also cp. *scripture, scroll ...*. My point being, again, that *chauk* (as the doublet of *chalk* is written) might be originally independent of Latin.

Comment: Now about *foke*, viz *folk*, Ger. *Volk*, I would prefer to just call it folk-etymology and be done with it. If I suggest hypercorrection played into all these examples, I shouldn't be hylercorrect about it myself. If I can, I will turn this into an answer.

Comment: @vectory That's an answer not a comment, my good sir.

Comment: @vectory I will upvote it if you put your comments into answer. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @HotLicks As I say in my question, there are also people that pronounce the L. I have also given the link of the reddit post. But I am not concerned about substandard pronunciations. Does any dictionary give any of those words with the pronunciation of L? I didn't find any but if you can find, please link.

Comment: @Sphinx - A lot depends on what you mean by "pronounce the L".  If you don't pronounce the L in "walk" it becomes "wok", for instance, and most people can tell the difference between these two words.

Comment: I wish to accept both the answers but the system is designed in such a way that I can only accept one answer to a single question. It is sad. Both the answers are spectacular!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the pairs *chalk, bald* and *chalk, milk,* the identity of both the consonant following the L and the vowel preceding the L could affect whether the L was lost. I'm not certain why, but my guess is that it's related to a more general pattern where only a restricted number of vowel sounds are permitted before syllable-final consonant clusters ending in labial consonants like /p b f v m/ or velar consonants like /k g/.

### K is a non-coronal consonant, while D is a coronal consonant

It might seem odd to group all of the above consonants together, but they all can be categorized as "non-coronal consonants". Coronal consonants are the class of consonants made with the front part of the tongue: dental or alveolar consonants such as /t d n s z θ ð/, and also the postalveolar consonants /tʃ dʒ ʃ ʒ/. The most common consonant sounds in English fall in the category of coronal consonants, and many non-syllabic suffixes, such as /d/~/t/ and /z/~/s/, consist of a coronal consonant.

For whatever reason, many English vowel sounds can be found before a consonant cluster in syllables ending in a coronal consonant, but cannot be found before a consonant cluster in syllables ending in a non-coronal consonant.

- For example, syllables ending in /st/ can have a variety of diphthongs or long/"tense" vowel sounds: *Christ* /aɪst/, *toast* /oʊst/, *oust* /aʊst/, *taste* /eɪst/, *hoist* /oɪst/, *east* /iːst/ *roost* /uːst/.
  In contrast, syllables ending in /sp/ or /sk/ are not found with diphthongs like /aɪ/, /aʊ/, /oɪ/, /oʊ/ or /eɪ/, and are only occasionally found with monophthongs that can be considered "long" such as *wasp* and (one pronunciation of) *Basque.*
- Syllables ending in /nt/ can be found with /aɪ/ (*pint*) /aʊ/ (*count*) or /eɪ/ (*paint*); syllables ending in [mp] or [ŋk] cannot (except for in some accents with a sound change of /æ/ to /eɪ/ before [ŋ]).

So I think there may actually have been a two-part sound change in Middle English, rather than an immediate vocalization of [l] to [w~ʊ].

- First, *a* and *o* before a consonant cluster starting in [l] were diphthongized to something like [aʊ] and [oʊ], respectively. This would create Middle English forms like [waʊlk], [saʊlt], [foʊlk], [boʊlt] from earlier [walk], [salt], [folk], [bolt].
- Then, to get rid of the ill-tolerated sequence of a diphthong followed by [lk] (a consonant cluster ending a non-coronal consonant), the consonant cluster was simplified by dropping the [l] (at least in some accents), resulting in [waʊk], [saʊlt], [foʊk], [boʊlt]. But the consonant clusters [lt] and [ld] were maintained after diphthongs because they end in coronal consonants.

In Modern English, the Middle English diphthong [aʊ] turned into a monophthong with different values in different accents. (The Early Modern English value is sometimes reconstructed as [ɒː].)

Vowels other than *a* and *o,* such as in *bulk, hulk, milk, silk, elk,* were apparently not diphthongized in this context, so the consonant cluster [lk] remained intact.

#### words with "l" followed by a labial consonant

Something similar would have occurred with [lf] [lv] [lm]. As with /lk/, we see no simplification of these clusters after *e* or *i*: *elf, shelf, shelve, elm, helm, film* and so on contain /l/. *Wolf* represents Old English *wulf* with respelling of *wu-* to *wo-.*

Words with "al" followed by a labial consonant show complicated developments. In some accents, such as British "Received Pronunciation", the *al* in words like *half, halve, calm* is pronounced as /ɑː/. This is not the usual outcome of the Middle English diphthong [aʊ], and it suggests that these words might have undergone an additional sound change, like [kalm] > [kaʊlm] > [kaʊm] > [kɑːm]. A change of [aʊ] to [aː] in this context might have been motivated by the fact that [ʊ] and labial consonants are both rounded, so the roundedness of [ʊ] might have been misinterpreted by a listener as just being part of the following consonant sound.

In American English, *half* and *halve* typically have /æ/, which could be the result of simplification of [aʊf] to [af] without lengthening. Something similar may have occurred in words such as *laugh(ter)* and *draught/draft.* *Calm* has a large variety of realizations in American English, some of which include an /l/.

For some reason, the word *scalp* (with p) shows /ælp/ in Modern English. I'm not sure how to summarize other words ending in *-lp* such as *palp, gulp, pulp, poulp.*

Other words I don't know how to summarize: *gulf, golf*; *-olv-* words like *solve revolve* etc.

#### words with "silent l" followed by a coronal consonant are irregular

Tchrist's answer mentions a few words spelled with LD that are pronounced without an [l] sound: *could/should/would* and for some speakers *solder.* I don't think any of these are related to a regular sound change.

*Solder,* a word with many pronunciations (including some with [l]), comes from French which had its own sound change of l-vocalization that applied before any consonant. The L was restored in the spelling and for some speakers in the pronunciation.

*Should* and *would* are probably cases of irregular loss of a consonant in a commonly used function word. For comparison, the consonant [k] has been lost in the past tense *made* of the common verb *make;* this is not part of any general pattern of [k] being lost. *Could* is an unetymological spelling by analogy with the spelling of *should* and *would.*

Comment: I know it isn’t this way for you, but words like *walk, talk, all, fall, call* have no low [ɑ] in them for many and perhaps most other native speakers, who have a higher back vowel there, [ɔ]. I know in your dialect you’ve lost [ɔ], or should I say that you’ve laahst aah? :) More seriously, the only word I have been able to come up with where I have a stressed [ɑl] is the imported word *phaal* [fɑl], which for me sounds nothing like *fall* [fɔɫ]. The import is lower, unrounded, and unvelarized, contrasting in all three traits with the native word. Only its velarization is non-phonemic for me.

Comment: A thorough and meticulously explained answer, thanks!

Comment: @herisson  Thank you for this authoritative account of the phonetics of it.  It might be worth adding that this is a very good instance of how language, including pronunciation, is a function of what ordinary people do rather than about rules, which, as in this case, explain rather than prescribe what they do.

Answer (score 4):

#### <sub>Please Note</sub>

<sub>In the following preamble leading up to the explanation, I am ***self-reporting*** how this all works for me personally so you can see where I’m coming from. I recognize that not everyone around the world talks the way I do. I am a native speaker
with the Inland North dialect of North America who was raised in the long lost rural southeastern Wisconsin of half a century ago before mass media inundation. I therefore have
the *father–bother* merger but **not** the *cot–caught* merger.
I also lack the Northern Cities Vowel Chain-Shift found in younger, more urban speakers from that region.</sub>

---

### *Usually* we keep the L

When it both follows a stressed vowel and also precedes another consonant
in that same syllable, phonemic /l/ is normally retained in pronunciation
compared with the written form.

With one exception, it does not matter
whether this is a **tense** vowel or a **lax** one, nor whether it is a **phonemic** diphthong (or even a *phonetic* diphthong, a notion I’ll ignore here for clarity).

- /ɑl/ —    (***none**, because the stressed FATHER vowel never occurs before* /l/ *for me in the coda*)
- /æl/ —    Alps, calc, calque, talc, scalp, shalt, Ralph, valve
- /el/ —    paled, baled, scaled, whaled, veiled, bailed, hailed, nailed, failed
- /ɛl/ —    Kelt, geld, belt, melt, smelt, meld, knelt, help, elk, whelk, elf, shelf, Guelph, delve, shelve, meld, realm, helm, wealth, twelfth, twelve, shelve, squelch
- /il/ —    field, shield, kneeled, yield
- /ɪl/ —    guilt, guild, built, build, bilge, kilt, killed, filled, filch, silk, milk, wilt, milled, film, filmed, kiln, sylph
- /ol/ —    colt, cold, hold, molt, mold, volt, told, sold, souled
- /ɔl/ —    Walt, waltz, fault, faults, salt, exalt, called, walled, galled, bawled, bald, golf, solve, alms, calm, calms, calmed, palm, balm, hauled, trawled, shawled, brawled, drawled, mauled, salsa
- /ul/ —    coolth, ruled, pooled, cooled, fooled, fuelled
- /ʊl/ —    pulled, hulk, sulk, wolf, wolves
- /ʌl/ —    cult, sculpt, skulled, ?skulk, sultan, nulled, hulled, bulge, gulf, false, pulse, bulk, bulb, gulled, gulp, gulped, culled, lulled, mulled, indulge
- /ɑul/ —   cowled, jowled, fouled, howled
- /ɑil/ —   wild, mild, tiled, smiled, styled, aisled, vialled, trialled
- /oil/ —   spoilt, oiled, toiled

### But not quite *always*

However, in a few words only, mostly common ones, the /l/ phoneme is completely lost in that position compared with the written form:

- /ɑ/ —    solder (*because I have the FATHER–BOTHER merger*)
- /æ/ —    calf, half, calves, halves, salve
- /o/ —    yolk, holm, ?folk, ?Polk
- /ɔ/ —    talk, walk, balk, caulk, chalk
- /ʊ/ —    could, would, should

As you see, the words where the /l/ has “gone missing” from the pronunciation are **mostly** words with lax vowels not tense ones there,
with *yolk* being the principal exception still in common use. Words like *folk* and *Polk* often lose the /l/, but not necessarily always.

## So what’s really happening here?

There do appear to be patterns that could be detected. For example, notice how there are no occurrences of /el/ or /il/ followed by an **unvoiced** stop.  Or how *kneeled* with a tense vowel becomes *knelt* with a lax one because the unvoiced stop checks the earlier vowel despite the intervening liquid.

The thing to remember here is that when we write phonemic /l/ — or /r/, or for that matter many other phonemes — we have deliberately clumped together any number of allophones that are all different sounds, but we’re trained not to hear them as different because they never result in a different word depending on which allophone shows up somewhere.

Consider *let* /lɛt/ and *tell* /tɛl/. Those two words have the same three phonemes; they merely swap the pair on the front and back with respect to each other.  But when you do that, you have to select different allophones. You are saying the same phoneme but **not the same *sound.***

The /t/ in *tell* is actually [tʰ], but the /t/ in *let* is just [t] or [ʔ]. And while for most speakers the /l/ in *let* is usually the voiced alveolar lateral approximant [l], the /l/ in *tell* may not be; it might instead be ***velarized*** alveolar lateral approximant written [ɫ] or [lˠ].

When you velarize the /l/ in the coda, it seems to get a bit mushy. When there’s a front vowel in front of it, as there is in *tell, tale, teal, till*, it may not velarize, or not much.  **Velarization** happens in the back of your mouth. So when there is a back vowel in front of it, as there is *tall, toll, pool, pull*, that velarization is stronger. It even changes the low back vowel [ɑ] to the open-mid back vowel [ɔ] as in *all, tall, fall, ball, call, Paul; almond, almost, balsam, balsamic*.  That even happens when I use the Spanish loanword *salsa* in English, where after naturalization from the original [ˈsalsa] in Spanish, it becomes [ˈsɔɫsə] like *Saul* or even [ˈsʌɫsə] like *Tulsa*.

The only word I know that retains an unmodified FATHER vowel [ɑ] there before final L is an import from India, the fiery dish variously spelled *phaal* or *phall* which is invariably pronounced [fɑl] or [fɑɫ], quite unlike how we pronounce our own word *fall* as [fɔɫ].

But you weren’t asking about words that end in ‹l›. You wondered about those that had ‹l› followed by another consonant. If that final consonant is a **velar** one, meaning unvoiced /k/ or voiced /g/, then the only chance you have to retain the dark, velarized ‹l› preceding it is if the vowel just before that is in the front of your mouth.  That’s why we still have an /l/ in *milk, whelk*: it’s because /ɪ/ and /ɛ/ are front vowels.

But with a back vowel **before** your **velarized** ‹l› and **velar** consonant **following** it, your mouth has no chance to produce any kind of distinct /l/ sound. Hence its disappearance in *talk, walk, balk, caulk, chalk, folk, Polk*. Interestingly, there are no words in English that end in the voiced version, /lg/.

The words where the /l/ is most often lost in many but not quite all speakers are just that sort of combination, like *folk* and *hulk*. I also know speakers who’ve lost it in *wolf, golf* but those are **back** vowels anyway, which destabilize the L even with a front consonant to follow (as long ago happened to *could, would, should*).

So what’s the excuse for losing it in *half, halves, calf, calves, salve*, given that those have a front vowel /æ/ before the L and a front consonant following it, especially since *talc, calque, elf, elves* preserves it?

I don’t know. Maybe it’s like the people who’ve lost it in *wolf* and *golf*. But I do wonder whether it doesn’t have its origin in the TRAP–BATH split, where speakers who distinguish those two vowels have a front vowel for TRAP but a **back** vowel for BATH. If it was a back vowel when the L was lost, that might explain it.

Comment: When you say you don't pronounce the /l/, do you mean that you merge yoke and yolk? Polk and poke?

Comment: @shoover Yes, I always pronounce *yolk* the same way I do *yoke*. I'm not sure I always say *Polk* like *poke* though. I think I may sometimes give its /l/ a half-hearted try. Not sure. But certainly I have no /l/ in *polka dots*.

Comment: It's a very enlightening and thorough answer, thanks! Both answers are so fascinating that I read them a few times but still want to read them again!

Comment: Like most BrE speakers, I _do_ pronounce the 'l' in _solder_. I use the BATH vowel for _half_, _calf_ etc, but I pronounce _salve_ with the 'l' and the TRAP vowel.

Comment: By the way, the 'l' in _could_ is analogical, and has never been pronounced AFAIK.